# How to print the values from a table into one by one value horizontally in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have data from DB as below.

```
Subject                         Mark   Grade
---------
COMPUTER SCIENCE               88.00 A2   
TAMIL                          88.00 A2   
HINDI                          55.00 C1   
MATHS                          54.00 C1   
SCIENCE                        77.00 B1   
ENGLISH                        45.00 C2
```

---

Using Jasper Report I have to print it like this:

```
Subject     COMPUTER SCIENCE   Tamil    HINDI    MATHS   SCIENCE   ENGLISH
GRADE           A2              A2       C1       C1       B1        C2
```

I put everything in detail band, but it prints like this

```
Subject     COMPUTER SCIENCE   COMPUTER SCIENCE     COMPUTER SCIENCE  
GRADE           A2                    A2                  A2
```

Same repeated for all the subject, hence it prints 6 times into separate detail band for all subject, but I want it to be

```
Subject     COMPUTER SCIENCE     TAMIL    HINDI                                    
GRADE           A2                 A2     C1
```

Please do some suggestions? I have tried with column count, report count, expression, but with no result

Comment: Have you tried somthing called crosstab in jasper report

Comment: yup i gave try with that one too but its not working. It just printed the SUBJECT : COMPUTER SCIENCE alone. Remaining data's are gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved using crosstab, in your example there is no `rowGroup` so we need to generate a dummy `rowGroup` on fixed String `"Grade"`, the `columnGroup` is on `$F{Subject}`

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="grades" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="407ecd26-3880-4351-b7f4-4422fa5adc32">
    <style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Subject" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Mark" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Grade" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="50">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50" uuid="c15de662-be8e-4db4-acef-1b71c3201725"/>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="07cab0ef-f928-4681-86ff-0c38656cdd31"/>
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Subject]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="dummy" width="70">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA["GRADE"]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="70" height="25" uuid="0ec80ead-fa81-4933-b56b-445e14578f6b"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{dummy}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="Subject" height="30">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Subject}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="30" uuid="304f31c2-426d-4177-aa32-bb7f6694cd6c"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Subject}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="GradeMeasure" class="java.lang.String">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Grade}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="62" height="25">
                    <cellContents>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="62" height="25" uuid="b10eac33-96fb-4d5d-8c3f-212c72192a3c"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{GradeMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="dummy">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="26fc7a85-7738-45e8-81ff-e076bb51d3fd"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{GradeMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="50" columnTotalGroup="Subject">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="82d05499-1fe2-4a97-ad82-23fa974759c5"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{GradeMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="dummy" columnTotalGroup="Subject">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="c6e4a9d8-6c74-4dcc-8617-18ad14e60890"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{GradeMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: Output]